# Move a vertical line horizontally inside a box

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am new to html5 canvas. I am trying to make a box on canvas. I want a vertical line (height equal to box height) inside this box. I want this line to move in horizontal direction, say on pause and play button. I am not able to make it. Can someone please help me in this?

I wrote the code which make a vertical line in a box.

```
class App extends Component {

    componentDidMount(){
        canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

        ctx.beginPath();

        ctx.moveTo(0,0);

        ctx.lineTo(0,200);

        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.fillStyle = "#808891";
    }


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

          <canvas id="DemoCanvas" width="500" height="200"></canvas>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

But I don't know how to make this line move in horizontal direction( Think it as marker for video timeline)

Comment: post your trying

Comment: @PandiyanCool check now

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a function which will first clean previously drawn line and then draw the new line at a specific X position.

Then, call this function with the new X position each time you need it, with requestAnimationFrame for example.

Here's a snippet with a play/pause button example.

```js
var left = 0;

const btn = document.getElementById("btn");
canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const w = canvas.width;
const h = canvas.height;

let xPos = 0;
let playing = false;

function updateVert() {
  if(!playing) {
    cancelAnimationFrame(updateVert);
    return;
  }
  
  xPos += 1;
  
  if(xPos >= w) {
    // stop animation...
    xPos = 0;
    playing = false;
    btn.value = "Play";
  }
  
  // reset rectangle content to erase previous line...
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
  
  // draw new one...
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#19f";
  ctx.lineWidth = 2;
  ctx.moveTo(xPos, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(xPos, 200);
  ctx.stroke();
  
  if(playing) requestAnimationFrame(updateVert);
}

document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if(playing) {
    // pause...
    playing = false;
  }
  else {
    playing = !playing;
    updateVert();
  }
  
  btn.value = playing?"Pause":"Play";
});
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid silver;
}
```

```html
<div className="App">
  <canvas id="DemoCanvas" width="200" height="80"></canvas>
</div>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Play">
```

Comment: Awesome. IS there any chance I can implement drag functionality also to the line?

Comment: Sure, but that's beyond the scope of this question. You'd better create a new one for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, it will create horizontal line based on given points

```js
canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath();
// Staring point
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
// End point
ctx.lineTo(500, 0);

ctx.stroke();

ctx.fillStyle = "#808891";
```

```html
<canvas id="DemoCanvas" width="500" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: the code I posted is correct. I want a vertical line and not the horizontal. Now I want to make that line move in horizontal direction line a slider.